# Нужно написать программу на c++ по обработке символьного масства

Tags: c++, массивы, символы

[![задание][1]][1]
Программирование c++
На вход поступают строки состоящие из слов из символоов, работаем посиивольно, нужно определить является ли комбинация символов словом при этом в строках встречаются цифрв пробелы двоеточия и тп.

Задача: Все последующие вхождения одинак слов нужно заменить на комбинацию s(n) где n номер первого вхождения слова

При этом все состоит из строчных структур которые входят в массив

( Я начал работать по такому принципу: создал пустой массив и последовательным сравнением символов, определяя слова начал его заполнять, проблема в том что при посиивольном сравнении, когда слово состоит например из 3 букв а заменить нужно на s(4), то в новый массив вводится только s(4 иначе теряется следующий символ

Comment: "Марина начал работать", но Марина забыл показать код со своей попыткой реализации и привести какие-то примеры входных данных и хотя бы желаемого результата.